# Logic for jQuery accordion, only open one item at a time but also close-on-click of open item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a really basic jQuery accordion (I'm aware of the accordion in UI, I do not want to use it).

I have the whole thing pretty much working, but am stuck on logic for one particular part.

### https://jsfiddle.net/sqnfs4kn/

Only one accordion item should ever be open at a time. So when the user clicks, I'm closing down all accordions regardless of the clicked one, and then opening the clicked one.

This works OK except I am missing **when the current, open item is clicked, it should close, so that no items are open at all**

I cannot figure out the logic for this because when the current item is clicked, it is currently set to open it if it has the `data-status="closed` but this does not seem to work.

Here is my accordion code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordian-item').click(function () {
        // close everything first
        $(".accordian-text").attr('data-status', 'closed');
        $("h3").css('background-image', 'url(arrow-down.png)');
        $(".accordian-text").css("height", "0").css('border-bottom', 'none');

        console.log('clicked!');
        var status = $(this).children(".accordian-text").attr('data-status');
        if (status == 'closed') {
            // open it
            $(this).children(".accordian-text").attr('data-status', 'open');
            $(this).children("h3").css('background-image', 'url(arrow-up.png)');
            $(this).children(".accordian-text").css("height", "auto").css('border-bottom', '1px solid #c7c5c5');
        } else {
            // close it
            $(this).children(".accordian-text").attr('data-status', 'closed');
            $(this).children("h3").css('background-image', 'url(arrow-down.png)');
            $(this).children(".accordian-text").css("height", "0").css('border-bottom', 'none');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing the open panel before checking the status.  Move

```
var status = $(this).children(".accordian-text").attr('data-status');
```

to the top of the function so it gets a status of "open" and your if logic will then go to the else.